# How to get a short URL for my website?

Tags: dns, short-url

These days I've seen a lot of websites using `Short URLs` for their whole websites instead of a single page reference.
Examples:

```
http://bo.lt
http://ge.tt
```

Just wondering how to get these type of custom URLs for my website. Can anyone let me know how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two letter high-level domains, such as .lt and .tt, belong to individual countries. .lt is Lithuania and .tt is Trinidad and Tobago. To get domains under these high-level country domains, just google for the domain name registrar for that country and register it just like you do a .com, .net, .org, etc.

Comment: Be aware that pricing is different for different TLDs. You can find a list of some common ones [here](http://www.name.com/pricing).